# Woes with installing and loading s.el

Tags: package

I'm running Emacs 27.1(9.0) on OSX 11.2.2 and have failed at installing and configuring the package `s.el` from https://github.com/magnars/s.el/ Here's a list of things that I tried:

1. Copied `s.el` into `~/.emacs.d/elisp/`
2. Added `(add-to-list 'load-path "/Users/username/.emacs.d/lisp")` # replace `username` with actual username
3. Verified that emacs does not complain when loading. Running `M-x s-trim-<TAB>` does **not** show any of the functions in `s.el`.
4. From the mini-buffer, loaded the file using `M-x load-file` and then typing `/Users/username/.emacs.d/lisp/s.el` - no errors observed here. However, `M-x s-trim<TAB>` does not display any functions in `s.el`
5. Opened up `s.el` in emacs, selected the first function `s-trim-right` and evaluated it with `C-x C-e`. Even though it evaluated without errors, `M-x s-trim<TAB>` does not list this function.
6. Repeat steps 1-5 from terminal by launching emacs with `emacs --debug-init`

I'm totally lost on how to get this working. The github page https://github.com/magnars/s.el/ says that the package can be installed by running `M-x package-install s`. However, `M-x package-install` does **not** list `s` as a valid package name. I only see a list of packages that have the letter `s` in their names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have loaded s.el properly. The functions you  are trying to call aren't interactive, what we call 'commands' in elisp. You can only call them from elisp code, they don't work with M-x.

Comment: Good Lord, thanks for clearing that up. I was losing my mind.